# How to use a list containing specific characters as markers for plot in python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have 4 lists referring to the x, y, z axes and a list containing the characters to be used as markers.
When printing the lists, they all have a column format. The 3D plot is working perfectly, without the addition of custom markers.
The list of bookmarks is as follows (in file <file_icons.txt>):

```
$O$
$H$
$H$
$O$
$H$
$H$
$O$
$H$
$H$
$O$
$H$
...
```

```
    data2=[]
    markers=[]
    with open('file_icons.txt') as file_icons:
            for line in file_icons:
                row = line.split()
                data2.append(row[:-1])
                markers.append(row[-1])
        markersS = np.asarray(markers, dtype=np.str, order='C')
```

And to plot I used the following:

```
    text_style = dict(horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='center',
                      fontsize=12, fontdict={'family': 'monospace'})
    marker_style = dict(linestyle=':', color='0.8', markersize=10,
                        mfc="C0", mec="C0")
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.4)
    marker_style.update(mec="None", markersize=5)
    fig = plt.figure(1)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax = Axes3D(fig)
    
    ax.plot(x,y,z,marker=markersS,**marker_style)
    
    fig.savefig('water_confined_3d.png',dpi=100)
    plt.show()
```

When trying to run, I get the following error:

ValueError: Unrecognized marker style array(['$O$', '$H$', '$H$', ..., '$Mo$', '$Mo$', '$Mo$'], dtype='<U4')

Trying a loop one by one (as follows) the program reads the list but writes all the markers at each of the plotted points.

```
for n in markersS:
    ax.plot(x,y,z,marker=n,**marker_style)
```

How could I get each marker to be written in its specific position? For example:
At x1, y1, z1, marker = marker1
...
xn, yn, zn, marker = markern

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide a [mcve]? - A fully working example with toy data would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `ax.plot` for every point separately if you want your points to be plotted using different markers:

```
for xi, yi, zi, mi in zip(x, y, z, markersS):
    ax.plot([xi], [yi], [zi], marker=mi, **marker_style)
```

Comment: I received: zs = np.broadcast_to(zs, len(xs)) TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()

Maybe because x,y,z are float, but markers is str?

Comment: No, that means, that the coordinates have to be iterables (of one element). See the edit